# Spring Data JPA Configuration with STS

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-data-jpa

I am getting following problem while configuring Spring Data JPA in STS

```
Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/.../war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-
 context-3.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd). 
- Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/.../war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-
 beans-3.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd). 
- Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/.../war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-
 beans-3.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd)
```

I am getting this error at this location on my applicationContext.xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The error gets disappear when I delete

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
```

from

```
<beans ...>
```

and

```
<jpa:repositories ... />
```

tag from XML.

Comment: Which STS Version do you use?

Comment: I am also getting a warning **Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for 
 namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class.** at <jpa:repositories .../> location

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the dialog

```
Window > Preferences > XML > XML CataLog
```

1.Click Window > Preferences and select XML > XML Catalog.

2.Click Add to create a new catalog entry.

```
Details:
Location:   D:\...\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\projects\org.springframework.beans\src\main\resources\org\springframework\beans\factory\xml\spring-beans-3.0.xsd
Key type:   Schema location
Key:        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

The other .xsd files which have error in xml file's firist line must be configured.

3.XML Configuration is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    ...
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    ...
    ..."
>
```

4.Editing `<bean: ...>` and other elements with automatical suggestions.